# How to add sprites in array C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, sprite

I want to access **game objects (sprites)** in my code in an **Array** but I have no idea how to do that, I am new to C#.

This is my testing code, but I am not getting any values:

```
void Start()
{

    Sprite[] countries = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("MAPS");
    sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    names = new string[countries.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        names[i] = countries[i].name;
        //0 = red
        //1 = green
        if (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2) == 0)
        {
            this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
        }
        else
        {
            this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your map textures stored in `Resources/MAPS` with that casing?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `this` keyword:

```
if (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2) == 0)
{
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
}
else
{
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;
}
```

try to use countries[i]:

```
if (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 2) == 0)
{
    countries[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
}
else
{
    countries[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;
}
```